# VHDL extend string literal to std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to convert a string literal like B"101" to C_NO_OF_CHANNELS bits std_logic_vector.

Doing:

```
library ieee, std, switch_core;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(B"101"), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS))
```

raises:

```
Type conversion (to UNSIGNED) can not have string literal operand.
```

Comment: Is `B"101"` a string literal or a std_logic_vector literal? For the latter one: `std_logic_vector(to_unsigned("101", C_NO_OF_CHANNELS))`. For the first one, you'll have to write a string to `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` parser.

Comment: `std_logic_vector(to_unsigned (to_integer(unsigned'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS));` The function `to_unsigned` (numeric_std, the first argument the natural to be converted, the second the natural size of the unsigned result) converts an integer  (natural) value to an unsigned with the specified size left '0' filled. A string literal is an array value, as is the equivalent string literal of a bit string literal while an integer is a scalar value.

Answer (score 1):

Between Paebbels comment and wahab's answer there are almost two working ways of converting the bit string literal to a resized std_logic_vector. Both methods can be corrected.

Paebbels' (corrected) method requires converting the bit string to an integer value first then using to_unsigned to convert the (natural) value to unsigned, then type converting to std_logic_vector:

```
std_logic_vector(to_unsigned (to_integer(unsigned'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS)); -- works
```

wahab's corrected and simplified method (using a qualified expression):

```
std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned'(B"101"), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS)); -- works
```

A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can be used to demonstrate both:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity extend is
end entity;

architecture foo of extend is
constant  C_NO_OF_CHANNELS:     natural := 42;
signal target: std_logic_vector (C_NO_OF_CHANNELS - 1 downto 0) := 
        -- std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(std_logic_vector'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS)); -- original - doesn't work
        -- std_logic_vector(to_unsigned (to_integer(unsigned'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS)); -- works
        std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned'(B"101"), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS)); -- works
begin
end architecture;
```

Note a constant value for C_NO_OF_CHANNELS has been provided.

The corrected wahab expression uses a qualified expression to disambiguate between two possible resize functions (signed and unsigned) the result of either capable of being type converted to std_logic_vector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(std_logic_vector'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS))`

Comment: That should be `std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(std_logic_vector'(B"101")), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS))` not the use of the apostrophe (`'`) between `std_logic_vector` and `(B"101")`, implementing a qualified expression. `std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned'(B"101"), C_NO_OF_CHANNELS));` will also work, disambiguating between a signed and unsigned resize.

Comment: That not should be note - 'note the use of the apostrophe'