# Bitshifting in VHDL creates errors

Tags: vhdl, bit-shift

I am trying to bitshift a std_logic_vector, but no matter what I try, I always get an error.

I I have tried to use srl and also shift_right, which I read is safer to use. Both of them are not accepted by the compiler or at least I am making a syntax error, that I can't find. I also tried to cast the result to std_logic_vector.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity EXAMPLE is
    port(
        VOL_LEVEL           : in integer range 1 to 10; -- from AUDIO_VOL
        LED_OUT             : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
    );
end entity EXAMPLE;

architecture BEHAVIOUR of EXAMPLE is

type STATES is (S_SET_VOL);

signal STATE, NEXT_STATE : STATES;

EXAMPLE: process(VOL_LEVEL)
begin
    case STATE is
        when S_SET_VOL =>

        LED_OUT <= ("1111111111") srl (10-VOL_LEVEL) after 2 ns; 
         -- Type error resolving infix expression "srl" as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_LOGIC_VECTOR.

        LED_OUT <= shift_right(unsigned("1111111111"), 10-VOL_LEVEL) after 2 ns;
         -- No feasible entries for subprogram "SHIFT_RIGHT".

        LED_OUT <= std_logic_vector(shift_right(unsigned("1111111111"), 10-VOL_LEVEL)) after 2 ns;
         -- Type conversion (to UNSIGNED) cannot have string literal operand.

end process EXAMPLE;

end BEHAVIOUR;
```

Comment: I presume that this is a test bench? In an entity which you want to synthesize you cannot use time information. i.e. `after 2 ns`

Comment: You need to tell us *which* error you get exactly.

Comment: I added comments

Comment: I have found in my use of VHDL that i prefer to write my own shifting functions, especially when you want to change the amount of shift which it looks like you will want to do. This can typically be achieved with a for loop and a section of pipelining. But again it depends as to whether you want it to be syntheizeable!

Comment: The example should be complete now

Comment: The third version should work if you use `to_unsigned` instead of `unsigned`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650504/vhdl-extend-string-literal-to-std-logic-vector

Comment: The second one is obviously wrong because the function is called `shift_right`, not `right_shift`.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9018087/shift-a-std-logic-vector-of-n-bit-to-right-or-left

Comment: I already tried solving it according to question 9018087 before, but something is not right with the syntax. There it also says to use "unsigned" and not "to_unsigned".